# Get <p> value using React ref

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

Is there some way to get this "name" value after clicking on li item and set it to selectedBranch state using ref?

```
  const [selectedBranch, setSelectedBranch] = useState(null);
  const selectRef = useRef();

  const selectDeliveryBranch = () => {};

  return (
    <li
      onClick={selectDeliveryBranch}
    >
      <p ref={selectRef}>{props.name}</p>
    </li>
```

Comment: `selectRef.target.innerText` should give you it, but it would seem pointless as you have it in `props.name` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to use ref to do this, instead simply create a callback:

```
return <li onClick={()=>setSelectedBranch(props.name)}>
    <p>props.name</p>
</li>
```

No ref needed

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure what to use and that is definitely better and easier way

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you need to use the ref ? Why can't you do that ?

```
const [selectedBranch, setSelectedBranch] = useState(null);
const selectRef = useRef();

return (
    <li
        onClick={() => setSelectedBranch(props.name)}
    >
        <p ref={selectRef}>{props.name}</p>
    </li>
```

Comment: Thank you! After this i am sure this is way better